# PHP - Multidimensional array merge to one array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have 2 arrays like this:

Array One:

```
[
    [
        "id" => 1234
        "name" => "John"
    ],
    [
        "id" => 1235
        "name" => "doe"
    ]
]
```

Array Two:

```
[
    [
        "age" => 12
    ],
    [
        "age" => 13
    ]
]
```

I have tried it using and combine `array_reduce`, `array_map` or `array_merge_recursive`, but it still doesn't match the results.

How can I make the two arrays like below?

```
[
    [
        "id" => 1234
        "name" => "John"
        "age" => 12
    ],
    [
        "id" => 1235
        "name" => "doe"
        "age" => 13
    ]
]
```

Please help me. thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[array-map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with combination of [array-merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) should do the trick:

```
$c = array_map('array_merge', $a, $b);
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/0cOR4)

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo link**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3369995d2b1f2c7215f61c12330022c668a4053c)

You could iterate the first array and merge with second array with respected index match

```
$merged =[];
foreach($a as $k => $val){
    array_push($merged,array_merge($val,$b[$k]));
}
print_r($merged);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_merge like :

```
<?php

$array = array(
                  ["id" => "1",  
                   "name" => "denba"
                 ],

                    ["id" => "1",  
                   "name" => "chpa7"
                 ],

              );              

$ages = array(
                  ["age" => "15",  

                 ],

                    ["age" => "17", 
                 ],

              );

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $array[$key]=array_merge($array[$key], $ages[$key]);
}


var_dump($array); 
/*output:
    array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "denba"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "15"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "chpa7"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "17"
  }
}
*/
```